# UIImage drawinrect method doesn't draw image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I have created a cust UIView class so that I can display the contents of a Map object.  After much research, I am still unable to determine why the method below doesn't draw anything:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    if(_map!=nil){
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"grass"];
        float w =  rect.size.width / _map.width;
        float h =  rect.size.height / _map.height;
        for(int x=0; x<_map.width; x++){
            for(int y=0; y<_map.height; y++){
                Tile *tile = [_map getTileAtX:x Y:y];
                UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:NSStringFromTileType(tile.type)];
                [img drawInRect:CGRectMake(x*w, y*h, w, h)];
            }
        }
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
}
```

I am calling `[mapView setNeedsDisplay]` to refresh the UIView.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: if you set a breakpoint on that "`UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`" line, will Xcode ever stop there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code  `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(...)` pushes new image context on top of the context of the view and `drawInRect:` draws the image into this new context. `UIGraphicsEndImageContext()` pops the image context destoying its contents. Pushing image context is usually used when you want to *create* UIImage, not when you need to *draw* its content into a context.

If you want to see the image - delete `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` and `UIGraphicsEndImageContext` calls.

Comment: great! It saved my time! I came to this answer after lot of search , before this I m thinking that it might not be possible for me to draw image somewhere in Current View! Thanks dear